# getting parent elements in xslt with python's lxml library

Tags: python, xslt, lxml

I'm new to lxml and xslt and trying to do the following - this is my xml:

```
<root>
<header>
    <h1>foo</h1>
</header>
<product>
    <a>something1</a>
    <b>something2</b>
</product>
<product>
    <a>something3</a>
    <b>something4</b>
</product>
</root>
```

Using lxml XSLT class, I want to go over each product element, and then apply some rules to it, for example:

```
def example():
example_xml = '''\
<root>
    <header><h1>foo</h1></header>
    <product><a>something1</a><b>something2</b></product>
    <product><a>something3</a><b>something4</b></product>
</root>'''
xslt_xml = etree.XML('''\
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <foo><xsl:value-of select="a" /></foo>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
    ''')
transform = etree.XSLT(xslt_xml)
doc = etree.parse(StringIO(example_xml))
root = doc.getroot()
for product in root.iterfind('product'):
    result = transform(product)
    print result
```

This example doesn't find a, only when I change the "match" attribute in the xslt_xml to match="product" this works. I thought match="/" means matching the root so I'm not sure why this doesn't work.

My bigger problem is that I want to also get information about elements that are ancestors or parents of product but this didn't work, i.e. this xslt doesn't return anything:

```
    xslt_xml = etree.XML('''\
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
        <xsl:template match="product">
            <foo><xsl:value-of select="../header/h1" /></foo>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
    ''')
```

so in the example code:

```
for product in root.iterfind('product'):
    print product.xpath('../header/h1/text()') #works
    result = transform(product)
    print result #doesn't work
```

Is it possible to access such elements if I'm running the xslt transform on product? I don't want to run the xslt on the whole document, I want to go over each product element and handle it, I know I can have the 'for each product' loop be done using xslt but I don't want that, this loop is external to the xslt processing.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why  your first example is not working seems to be a slightly misunderstanding about root. 
E.g. [**root node**enter link description here](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/root.html#d8857e301)
*The top of the tree is a root node (1.0 terminology) or document node (2.0). This is what "/" refers to. It's not an element: it's the parent of the outermost element (and any comments and processing instructions that precede or follow the outermost element). The root node has no name.*

There is no "a" element as child of the root node. The child of root node is your root element.

The next point you have to consider about art the  [Built-in Template Rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule).
This is the reason why your second example

seems to work. But the output should be:

```
             foo

   <foo>something1</foo>
   <foo>something3</foo>
```

But unclear for me is your third result: 
With this template:

```
<xsl:template match="product">
    <foo>
        <xsl:value-of select="../header/h1" />
    </foo>
</xsl:template>
```

The output should/(would) be:

```
            foo

    <foo>foo</foo>
    <foo>foo</foo>
```

To avoid the first lonely "foo". You have have to avoid the build-i template rules.
For example try:

```
<xsl:template match="/*" >
    <xsl:apply-templates select="product" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="product">
    <foo>
        <xsl:value-of select="../header/h1" />
    </foo>
</xsl:template>
```

Update:
They above statements are only right if transform is called for the xml document.
But transform() is called for product nodes (`for product in root.iterfind('product'):`).
From xslt point of view this product node is now the **document**. (There is not context node form stylesheet point of view)  Therefor it is not possible to access any parent or sibling of this.

IF you like to use xslt it would be best to use the transfer call for the xml document. 
And then iterate over the result (if needed).

This stylesheet:

```
xslt_xml = etree.XML('''\
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:template match="/" >
     <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//product" />
     </root>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="product">
            foo><xsl:value-of select="../header/h1/text()" />,<xsl:value-of select="a" /></foo>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
    ''')
```

You can iterate through the new foo nodes.

```
transform = etree.XSLT(xslt_xml)
doc = etree.parse(StringIO(example_xml))
root = doc.getroot()
result = transform(root)
# print (str(result ))

for foo in result.iterfind('foo'):
    print (foo.text)
```

Output:

```
foo,something1
foo,something3
```

Comment: Hi hr_117, thanks for your detailed answer but when I try what you wrote it still doesn't work and nothing is printed.

Comment: @user1833691 Sorry seems I did not look close enough to the Python code. My statement should be right if you use the transfer for the whole xml document. I think what you try to do would not work. (Stay with xpaht or use xslt for the document.)

Comment: Thanks hr_117, unfortunately I can't run the xslt on the whole document in my specific scenario, I need to do it for each product element. As you said, I guess I can't use xslt..